# How to print from conmand line in bash

Tags: linux, bash

How to print from command line starting at X position?
For example if we say print from 5th position and the command line is:

```
One two three four five six
```

It should display:

```
five six
```

(PLEASE NOTE: that I do not want it to have new lines in between meaning the output I desire is five six, and not
five
Six
Each in new line)
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Parameter expansion is an appropriate tool for this job:

```
$ set -- one two three four five six
$ echo "${@:5}"
five six
```